# Will Windows Phone 8 app run on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

I have some apps developed with Windows Phone SDK 7.1 which undoubtedly run on Windows Phone 8 without any change.

My question is the other way. If I upgrade my app WP7 apps to WP8, meaning I make necessary namespace changes and compile them with WP8 SDK, will they still run on WP7? - I guess no.

What should be my strategy to have apps that run on both of the OS and still I should be able to use advanced functionality (if it runs on WP8) that WP8 offers (like Wallet, NFC, Nokia Imaging and more stuff like that)?

Is that I need to create 2 separate versions of each app? One will run on WP7 built with WP7 SDK and will not have advanced functionality like Wallet, NFC Sharing. The other app will have all of them and built with WP8. Will they be two separate apps in Windows Phone Marketplace?

Comment: http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Maintaining_a_WP7_and_WP8_version_of_a_same_Silverlight_application

Comment: Thank you KooKiz for the link. I understand what you are trying to say. Do mean to say, I need to submit 2 separate apps to the store - one for WP7 and one for WP8?

Comment: You don't need to submit two separate apps, DevCenter allows you to submit a distinct XAP for the WP7 and WP8 version of a same app

Comment: oh, I got you now. could you please get me some a link about it.

Comment: A link about what? Submitting two XAP? It's straightforward, after uploading the first XAP of your app, click on "add new" to upload the second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 apps will run on Windows Phone 8, but the reverse is not possible. The former is called backwards compatibility.

If you want to support WP 7 OS, you need to maintain two different applications and submit them *independently* to the store.